# Which sentences in S := {"the number of lies in S is a multiple of n" | n = 1,...,120} are true in every possible non-contradictory case?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, algorithm

Consider the set
$S := \{$ "the number of lies in the set $S$ is a multiple of $n$" $|$ $n = 1, 2, 3, ... , 120 \}$.

Question: Which elements/sentences in the set $S$ are true in every possible non-contradictory case?

Or, in other words:

Does there exist $v$ in $\{0, 1\}^{120}$ satisfying that: the $n$-th component of $v$ is $0$ if and only if the number of $0$ components in $v$ is a multiple of $n$? Which components of $v$ are $0$ if $v$ exists?

$T = \{ n$ divides $|F|: n$ in $\{1,...,120\} \}$ and $F = \{ 1,...,120 \} - T$. Solve the "set equation(s)" for $T$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let x be the number of lies in the set (0 to 120, inclusive).

A computer scan determines that the values of x leading to a non-contradictory situation are

> 0 (all sentences are true) and 108 (= 2^2 * 3^3, so sentences 1 2 3 4 6 9 12 18 27 36 54 108 are true and the rest are false).

so the desired answer is

> the sentences from the 108 case.

In general, for a set of any size,

> 0 lies is always non-contradictory, and a non-zero number of lies is non-contradictory if and only if the number plus its number of divisors (including itself) equals the size of the set. The number of the divisors is the product of (exponent + 1) over the exponents in its prime factorization. (Edited to fix the mistake that Jaap Scherphuis pointed out.)

Comment: Your very last sentence is not quite correct.

Comment: I feel the narrative flow of the answer might be improved quite a bit by starting with the final spoiler block that describes how to find the non-contradictory cases, and only then proceeding to apply that technique.

Comment: Jaap Scherphuis: Thanks, I edited it to fix that part.